# Where do Before and After hooks go in Cucumber

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cucumber, hook

I have a fairly simple Cucumber test framework with a feature file, a step definitions file, and a test runner class that looks like this:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java/com/tests/cucumber/features/ui/ExampleTest.feature", 
                 glue = { "com.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions" },
                 )
public class ExampleTestRunner {

}
```

This runs a scenario in the feature file just fine. Now I want to add a Before and After hook to do some setup and teardown, but I can't for the like of me get the hooks to run. I've tried adding the hooks to the ExampleTestRunner and to the StepDefinition class, but they never run. Where should I put these hooks? At the moment, the hooks just look like this, but I'll add content to them once I've worked this out!

```
package com.tests.cucumber.stepdefinitions;

import cucumber.api.java.After;
import cucumber.api.java.Before;

public class StepDefinitions {

    @Before
    public void before() {
        System.out.println("starting before()");
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It should work when the hooks are placed in the step definition or any class inside the packages mentioned in the glue value. Are u sure u are importing the cucumber before annotation and not the junit one?

Comment: I have added the StepDefinitions class to the question. As far as I know, it's importing the correct annotation, but I'm still learning!

Answer (score 0):

I am a little hesitant to answer this question even though I managed to get this to work. As far as I can tell, the problem was that I had added the Before and After methods in classes that were extended by other classes. In this situation, the tests would not run. I had to add the Before and After methods to a class that was not extended.

It feels like this is similar to the situation in which if you specify a step definition in a class that is extended by another class, then the step definition is considered to have a duplicate definition. Do I have the correct diagnosis here?

Answer (score 0):

I use like this;

Runner Class:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(

    features = {"src\\test\\features\\ui_features"},
    glue = {"com\\base\\tm\\auto_reg\\tests\\ui_tests\\price_features"},
    plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:"}
)

public class PriceFeatureRunner {
@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    RunnerUtil.setup(PriceFeatureRunner.class);
}

@AfterClass
public static void teardown() {
    RunnerUtil.teardown();
}

}
```

RunnerUtil.java:

```
public class RunnerUtil {
public static void setup(Class<?> clazz) {
    String reportPath = "target/cucumber-reports/" + clazz.getSimpleName().split("_")[0] + "_report.html";

    ExtentProperties extentProperties = ExtentProperties.INSTANCE;
    extentProperties.setReportPath(reportPath);

}


public static void teardown() {
    UiHooks uiHooks = new UiHooks();
    uiHooks.afterScenario();
    ExtentReportConfiguration.configureExtentReportTeardown();
}
}
```

UiHooks.java

```
public class UiHooks implements HookHelper {


public static final String BASE_URL = "https://www.stackoverfow.com/";

private Scenario scenario;

@Override
@Before
public void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario) {
    this.scenario = scenario;

    Reporter.assignAuthor(System.getProperty("user.name"));
}

@Override
@After
public void afterScenario() {

   if (HookUtil.driver != null) {
        HookUtil.driver.quit();
    }
    if (HookUtil.seleniumBase != null) {
        HookUtil.seleniumBase.stopService();
    }

}

@Override
@After
public void afterTest() {
   if (HookUtil.driver != null) {
        HookUtil.driver.quit();
    }
    if (HookUtil.seleniumBase != null) {
        HookUtil.seleniumBase.stopService();
    }
}
```

}

HookHelper.Java

```
public interface HookHelper {

@Before
void beforeScenario(Scenario scenario);

@After
void afterScenario();

void afterTest();
}
```